# Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)[x]/(x^4-t^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ be the field of two elements. Let $R=\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)[x]/(x^4-t^2)$.

Why is $R/J(R)$ equal to $\mathbb{F}_{2}(t)[x]/(t-x^2)$? here $J(R)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of $R$.

Comment: To what element of $F_2(t)$ would an isomorphism send $x \in F_2(t)[x]/(x^2-t)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you actually mean to say "quotient of $R$ by its Jacobson radical" rather than "Jacobson radical of $R$", as $\mathbb{F}_2(t)[x]/(x^2-t)$ is naturally a quotient of $R$, not an ideal of $R$.

The Jacobson radical always contains the nilradical, and $x^2-t$ is nilpotent in $R$.  So it suffices to show $S=\mathbb{F}_2(t)[x]/(x^2-t)$ has trivial Jacobson radical.  But $x^2-t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$, so $S$ is actually a field.

Comment: I don't understand much from this answer (and from the question as well): why the Jacobson radical is a ring/field when this is by definition an ideal?

Comment: I assumed that in the question, "Jacobson radical" actually meant "quotient by the Jacobson radical".

Comment: I'd have never thought to such assumption. Anyway, in such case I think you should have mentioned this in your answer.

Comment: Yes, I have now edited to mention that.  I confess that when I first read the question, I didn't even notice that it said "Jacobson radical" instead of the quotient.  Apparently my misreading was the intended one, given that they chose to accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Jacobson radical of $R$ is, by definition, the intersection of maximal ideals of $R$. In our case $R$ is local with the maximal ideal $(x^2+t)/(x^2+t)^2$. If we want to see this as an $R$-module, then we can conclude that it is isomorphic to $R/(x^2+t)$, but I can't see how is this isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2(t)[x]/(x^2+t)$ (which is actually isomorphic to $R/J(R)$).

Comment: you're of course right; apologies! (I edited the question now), thanks for your remark.